# how to remove the title bar in jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FirstFrame extends JFrame {


    //FirstFrame properties

    public FirstFrame(){

        setTitle ("Stacker");
        setSize (380,650);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible (true);
        setUndecorated (true);
        setResizable(false);

    }
public static void main (String[] args){
        new FirstFrame();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to remove the toolbar above because I want to put buttons in the frame that will contain exit, and play button. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order of events in your constructor from this:

```
    setTitle ("Stacker");
    setSize (380,650);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible (true);
    setUndecorated (true);
    setResizable(false);
```

To this:

```
    setTitle ("Stacker");
    setSize (380,650);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated (true);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible (true); // move setVisible to the end
```

Comment: thank you so much! sorry if my question is already duplicated/. i just wanna understand it with my own code! thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome! Personally I didn't consider this question a duplicate because you used the correct syntax to make the frame go away, the order was just wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is, you've made the frame visible before you've set undecoratable

> Disables or enables decorations for this frame.
> **This method can
>   only be called while the frame is not displayable**. To make this frame
>   decorated, it must be opaque and have the default shape, otherwise the
>   IllegalComponentStateException will be thrown. Refer to
>   Window.setShape(java.awt.Shape), Window.setOpacity(float) and
>   Window.setBackground(java.awt.Color) for details

So, instead of...

```
    setVisible (true);
    setUndecorated (true);
```

You should try...

```
    setUndecorated (true);
    setVisible (true);
```

Comment: thank you so much! sorry if my question is already duplicated/. i just wanna understand it with my own code! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable or enable decorations for the frame while the frame is not displayable. See [setUndecorated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) for details. Reverse the order in your code - first call `setUndecorated (true);` then call `setVisible (true);`,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setUndecorated(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use frame.setUndecorated(true); but you never set up a frame so just put setUndecorated under setResizable